# Why Date field is coming with Character T in JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am trying to retrieve and Save  Date from Oracle Table using JPA .  The column type is DATE in Oracle.
In JPA entity i configured as

```
@Column(name = "NOTE_DATE")
private Date  noteDate;
```

In Json why i am getting the date with a T character . Eventhough its not saving that (T)character   ins DB why its asking for date as

Successful Save

```
"noteDate": "2021-11-01T20:00:05"
```

Failure Save

```
"noteDate": "2021-11-01 20:00:05"
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`; both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Hibernate 5 handles java.time nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `2021-11-01T20:00:05` date representation is generated by your JSON serializer which converts your `Date` to `String` and not by JPA. By default, Spring uses Jackson as JSON serializer which converts `Date` to its [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation.

For your error when you try to save your object using

```
"noteDate": "2021-11-01 20:00:05"
```

For me, it is a deserialization problem: Jackson can not convert your JSON to your Java object.